# Store Object Value Inside an Object

Tags: java, list, object

I would like to store my multiple value in my object like this:

```
public class Student extends StudentModules{
    //Initialization
    private String mName;
    private String mNICN;

    private String Module1;
    private int ExamScore1;
    private int AssignmentScore1;

    private String Module2;
    private int ExamScore2;
    private int AssignmentScore2;

    private String Module3;
    private int ExamScore3;
    private int AssignmentScore3;
```

As seen here, I want to create each student a Module, which Associates with its score:

```
Module 1 -> Exam1 -> Score1
Module 2 -> Exam2 -> Score2
Module 3 -> Exam3 -> Score3
```

So that in order to access the score of each module of each student possible.
I currently able to being worked when forced, (Create Variable for each Module). So I want to create Object to store the group of Module with its score.

This is my path:

```
1. When user register, call Student class (Above)
2. Inside student class, I can create Module, with its score
```

So when I access student Object I can access their score, modules might be using arraylist, so I can index it on  what module name to be taken.

Thanks anyway guys for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you should have another class, with a `String` and two `int`s, and then have an array or list of those.

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work ? also, it seems like a really bad design to have Student extend StudentModules as I don't think we can qualify a Student as being a StudentModules ...

Comment: Yeah, so i would like to create an object that stores both module and score, so that I can access it individually (Each module each score)

Answer (score 1):

So why won't you define a Module class and have a collection of those?

```
class Module {
    String name;
    int score1;
    int score2;

}

List<Module> modules;
```

UPD: Please see this example. You can add getters for fields you need.

```
class Student {
    final List<Module> modules;

    Student(List<Module> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }
}


class Module {
    private final String name;
    private final int score1;
    private final int score2;

    Module(String name, int score1, int score2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score1 = score1;
        this.score2 = score2;
    }
}

class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student andrewWatson = new Student(Arrays.asList(new Module("Module1", 95, 90), new Module("Module1", 65, 80)));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so I can't just access `Module`, I need to go from `Student -> Module`, So in your case, I create a class `Module`, and inside `Student` (Each Object). In `Main Class` I will call by `Student setter`, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Please see the example I've added